Can logical assertions be read as not having some or any implications?
Is there a way to restrict the implication of a claim? In other words, is it possible to express truths in logic that do not have logical implications, and if so does this have a name in logic and epistemology?
For example, if I say that a backpack doesn't have books, I want the insertion read as I'm not implying that it contains another element or lacks any other element. I'm simply denying a specific set of elements -- books.
Thanks in advance.

There is no term "implicative truth". You may have something like Grice's conversational implicatures in mind, "something the speaker suggests or implies with an utterance, even though it is not literally expressed". There are common conventions on implicating information that is not spelled out, and when speakers do not intend to do that they are expected to say so explicitly. "This backpack doesn't have books" will often implicate that it has something else. Otherwise, one would be expected to say outright that it is empty.

You are just negating the proposition "There are books in the backpack" by saying "The backpack does not contain books".

@Conifold Right, what I have in mind is what Grice says. The problem is that I don't want to state generically that the backpack is empty, but that it is empty of just one type of element.

@KristianBerry The function would be in the negation of something, if I understand your question. I assert x as a function of the absence of y. Does that make sense?

@JoWehler And does that denial have some kind of concrete name, or is it simply a denial?

@Ian I do not know a name different than negation. And I do not see the necessity to create one. - Why do you think it is a question for philosophy?

In standard logic and semantics what is stated is already interpreted to have no implicatures, just as you want. However, people rarely interpret colloquial statements literally in practice. If you do not want to be misunderstood you will have to emphasize your meaning. For example, "this backpack may or may not have some stuff but it doesn't have books." See SEP, Pragmatics on how literal meaning is modified in practical contexts.

What is your motivation for asking a question like this?

@D.Halsey I want to know if there is a Western equivalent, in logic and epistemology, to what the Gelukpa call non-implicative negation (med dgag) to deny the absence of svabhava of phenomena and things.

@KristianBerry It might be relevant, but I can’t think of any direct connection to my question right now, beyond that f(x) doesn't equal anything at all.


Is it possible to express non-implicative truths in logic?

Logically speaking, every truth implies itself. If φ is true, then φ is true. That is, the truth of φ implies the truth of φ. Nothing to do with φ. It is how the implication works.

For example, if I say that a backpack doesn't have books, I'm not implying that it contains another element or lacks any other element. I'm simply denying a specific set of elements -books.

If I say that φ is true, what I say doesn't imply the sentence "It is false that φ". It doesn't implies many other sentences, a non-countable infinity of them.
Still, If I say that φ is true, what I say implies φ. It also implies φ ∨ ψ, ψ → φ, φ ≡ φ etc. Whatever we say, what we say implies a non-countable infinity of truths, most of them totally trivial and uninteresting.
However, if we say for example that the sun is shining, we are not going to have in mind all the non-countable infinity of sentences which are implied by the sentence "the sun is shining". Usually, the non-trivial implications of what we say in a natural language are deniable. That is, we can always claim that the implication was not what we meant.

I understand. My problem is determining if the statement implies only itself. For example: "this dog is not a male dog" would imply that it is a female dog, but I just want to negate the "male" part of the dog without asserting anything else.

I’m confused. How can there be an uncountable infinity of sentences if every word and sentence is finite?

@Ian "My problem is determining if the statement implies only itself." It doesn't. Every meaningful sentence implies an infinite number of other sentences and there is nothing you can do about it. You may only mean p, but p implies p ∨ p, q → p, p ≡ p etc. However, these are trivial and uninteresting. Some non-trivial and interesting sentences will inevitably be implied. For example, the sentence "this dog is not a male dog" implies "there is a dog there", "there is at least one dog", "there is an animal" etc., and some more philosophical sentences such as "There exists something" etc.

@PW_246 "How can there be an uncountable infinity of sentences if every word and sentence is finite?" One reason is p ⊢ p ∨ q. The rest is self-evident.

@Speakpigeon again, don’t go with your gut, since it’s not correct. Unless you’re assuming an infinitary language, you only have countably many possible formulas. The argument is similar to the fact that the rational numbers are countable.

@PW_246 "again, don’t go with your gut" I prefer to use my gut to digest and my intuition to think. Everybody has to anyway because there's nothing else to start from. I just verified what I say in my answer, it's all good! I can only assume you're making yet again some unwarranted assumption about what I mean. You should try to ignore me.

@Speakpigeon please link the page that properly explains what  you mean.

@PW_246 "please link the page that properly explains what you mean" https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/117722/can-logical-assertions-be-read-as-not-having-some-or-any-implications/117738?noredirect=1#comment369592_117738

@Speakpigeon so as usual, you’re saying nothing but hot air.

@PW_246 Do I have to explain everything? You think I am your private logic teacher? You should stop obsessing about me.

@Speakpigeon No, you’re not my private Logic teacher, but I’m basically yours. I honestly can’t believe someone like you exists, which is why I’m testing the limits of human arrogance and illogicality by seeing when you’ll admit you’re wrong. You got close before, but now you’re just making dumb claims.

The point is you can’t do Cantor’s diagonal argument here because there are no sentences or words of infinite length.
